Xcode 16 issues, npm run ios no longer working
As the title suggests I recently upgraded my macOS version which in turn made me update my Xcode to version 16.0, because of this the app that I was developing would work fine on version 15.4. I got it to the point where the simulator would run however then the simulator would fail to download my app and run it developmentally.
❌ error: unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios15.0-simulator' (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC-framework' from project 'Pods')
This is the main error which keeps appearing.
I've tried re-cloning my repo just to try different methods. Went through stack overflow and modified my podfile, tried adjusting my build settings and so on for my target app, but I'm not having any luck at all. Even tried updating my podfiles, cleaning the builds, etc.
Note: My teammates who haven't upgraded their iOS or xcode can run it just fine.

There's a new version of BoringSSL compatible with Xcode 16 since that morning.
Check out: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

Looks like BoringSSL-GRPC-framework needs to be updated for ios 16.
For my project, it was react-native-firebase. Updating to the latest version  fixed the issue.
Thanks to @Mik378 for the tip

Worked for me, thanks!

I’m still unable to spin it up with Xcode 16, however I was getting an error with BoringSSL I was able to create a temporary fix for. If you place your post install function with this one it should help with that error. Minus the "Flutter" Loop If you’re not running Flutter (I’m not myself). I guess Xcode 15 ignored the -G Flag however Xcode 16 enforces it, so essentially just need to tell Xcode to ignore it. I can just a temporary fix when I was able to use.
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


I am facing with the same issue with you, i am no longer able to build my project after upgrading to xcode 16 and sequoia. I also did similar things to resolve the issue, but none of worked.
Additionally: Some articles like below was suggesting try run xcode with rosetta but i also don't have any options to make it run with rosetta:
https://handi.dev/blog/how-run-react-native-on-macbook-m1-apple-silicon
Here is the error i am getting while building:
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')
note: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'myapp' from project 'myapp')
note: Run script build phase '[Expo] Configure project' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'myapp' from project 'myapp')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RN]Check rncore' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Fabric' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')


--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:71DE56AB-FBF1-49D9-8EF1-16B10C1FF2D6, OS:18.0, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:71DE56AB-FBF1-49D9-8EF1-16B10C1FF2D6, OS:18.0, name:iPhone 11 }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/ahmet_argon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-emsufujfbgeaqgfvunvuggmstnyj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Script-46EB2E0001AE40.sh (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
        Building workspace myapp with scheme myapp and configuration Debug
(2 failures)
Build logs written to /Users/ahmet_argon/Documents/Babella /test-app/my-app/.expo/xcodebuild.log

